# exim + vexim + Squirrel install howto for newbie?

Tags: debian, installation, spamassassin, exim

is there any nice step by step tutorial for 100% newbie how to install

- exim
- vexim
- Squirrel
- SpamAssassin (maybe)

on a **Debian** box with LEMP?

I want to be able

- send, receive, forward email on
  multiple domains
- read emails via web
  interface
- (maybe) filter spam mail

Answer (score 1):

SME server (http://wiki.contribs.org) is based on CentOS, but can accomplish what you listed very easily (and more).

Comment: hm, not sure if I can use that on linode.com

Comment: You can always ask...